# Instantiating array in a for loop to create JTextFields

Tags: java, arrays, applet, jtextfield

I need to use a forloop and the text_fields instance variable to instantiate each
text field, make it a listener, and add it to the applet.
The text_fields variable is an array which has a max number of arrays of 2.

```
Container c = getContentPane();

c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


 int i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < FIELDS; i++)
 {
   THIS IS WHERE I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO WRITE.
       i need to instantiate the arrays, make them listeners and 
       add them to the applet.


 }
```

Comment: Any example code for what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if `FIELDS` is your `JTextField` array or a constant. If it is the component array itself, consider using the `.length` array field when iterating. This reduces code maintenance:

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
   fields[i] = new JTextField("Field " + i);
   fields[i].addActionListener(myActionListener);
   c.add(fields[i]);
}
```

Note uppercase variables are used for constants under Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
Container c = getContentPane();

c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JTextField[] txt = new JTextField[FIELDS]; // FIELDS is an int, representing the max number of JTextFields

 int i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < FIELDS; i++)
 {
   txt[i] = new JTextField();
   // add any listener you want to txt[i]
   c.add(txt[i]);
 }
```