# How can I create a JTextField array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I want to add many text fields for my project and decided to just use arrays because all those 22 text fields have the same attributes.

I had tried `JTextField txtFld[] = new JTextField[5];`. it has no parameter errors but when I try to run my program, this shows up in the console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't want to use

```
JTextField txtFld[] = new JTextField[]{
    new JTextField(10),
    ...
    ...
    ... // repeat the same code about 20 times
};
```

Because it takes up so many lines and the text fields are of the same type anyway. All I want to do is an array of text fields with the same length and just use `mainPanel(txtFld[0]); ... mainPanel(txtFld[21]);`

Is it possible to create a text field array in just a single line of code?

Comment: Have you considered using a loop? All `new JTextField[5]` does is create an array with _space for_ 5 text fields. But doesn't actually fill it with any `JTextField` objects. Objects are create with the `new` key word. So if you don't want 20 lines of code, you can shorten it to 3 with a loop.

Comment: Maybe a refresher on [How to use Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)  and [How to Use for Loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm new to SO, I could just answer the question but it's a repeated question. I'm writing the answer:

It's unclear is FIELDS is your JTextField aray or a constant. If it is the component array itself, consider using the .length array field when iterating. This reduces code maintenance:

```
Container c = getContentPane();
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[22];
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
   fields[i] = new JTextField("Your Value");
   //you can add any listener for JTextField here
   c.add(fields[i]);
}
```

Note uppercase variables are used for constants under Java naming conventions.

**The answer's been copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195458/3341891)**. I couldn't mark this question as duplicate.